# Flex 4, listen an event from parent

Tags: events, flex4, addeventlistener, event-listener, dispatchevent

I have the following problem:

**Description:**

I have a page with a button and a spark list (spark.components.List), when the button is clicked, all the elements in the list should change their label.

The list uses a custom item renderer to display the data (The renderer is a spark item renderer: s:ItemRenderer and the data that will be displayed comes from database).

When I click the button, I dispatch an event "button_clicked", that event should be listened by all the elements in the custom item renderer.

In the renderer, I have this function that should listen to the "button_clicked" event:

```
public function init():void 
{
this.addEventListener("button_clicked", button_clicked);
}

public function button_clicked(event:Event):void 
{
mdm.Dialogs.prompt("Button clicked event dispatched");
}
```

**Problem:**
The method "button_clicked" is never executed, which means that the event is not listened in the item renderer.

Anyone that can help me to understand how to dispatch an event in a parent and listen to it in the ItemRenderer object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780951/flex3-custom-item-renderer-does-not-listen-to-events-dispatched-by-parent):

> In renderer's init(), you need to add
>   an event listener not to the renderer,
>   but to the container which dispatches
>   the event.

**Example:**

```
container.addEventListener(Container.SELECT_ALL_USERS, selectAllHandler, false, 0, true);
```